# Play Framework JSON Reader and custom JSErrors

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I'm trying to read a JSON that could have the following parameters coming from the client

```
{
   "email" : "foobar@gmail.com",
   "password" : "XXXX",
   "facebookToken": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

The **facebookToken** could be Null or Not present, in which case the **Email/Password** should be filled, and vice versa.

I'm having trouble constructing this Reader, here's what I have so far:

```
val loginEmail = (
  ( __ \ "email").read[String] and
  ( __ \ "password").read[String]
)((email: String, password: String) => new User(email, password))

val loginFacebook = (
  ( __ \ "facebookToken").read[String]
)((facebookToken : String) => new User(facebookToken))

val loginReader(RequestBodyJson) = (
    (RequestBodyJson).read[User](loginEmail) or
    (RequestBodyJson).read[User](loginFacebook)
)
```

Can anyone show me how to do this correctly?

I would also like it to return JSError with customized messages. For instance, if the FacebookToken is not present, and there was something wrong with the Email ("Email was Invalid") instead of "/facebookToken path not found" generic error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this tricks:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._
import play.api.data.validation.ValidationError

....
(__ \ "facebookToken").read[String].orElse(Reads(_ => JsError(ValidationError("custom-error"))))
```

You can return a custom JsError if the main reader fail.

Comment: That looks reasonable. But what is the proper way to compose OR combination of readers as a Single Reader in my use case?

Comment: I've just updated the code, there was a mistake... is this solution better ? (I've not understand your question)

Comment: Sorry for the vague question, but here's what I would like:

Create a Reader that Returns a JSSuccess with the User Object if either FacebookToken or Email & Password are parsed correctly. Or Returns a custom error message by changing JSError

I understand how to change the error now from your explanation, but I'm still unclear as how to construct the JSSuccess case in one Reader if that's possible